# Lithium chloride is soluble in pyridine while other lithium halides are not. Why?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility

> Lithium chloride is soluble in pyridine while other lithium halides are not. Why?

I know that lithium chloride is deliquescent like magnesium chloride. Lithium halides are covalent and thus are soluble in organic solvents. Then, why is it that only lithium chloride is soluble in pyridine?

Comment: I was told that, since the solvation energy of LiCl is more, so its soluble. But this doesn't clear my doubt.

Comment: @Mithoron, i know that alkali metal halides are mostly ionic solids, but, Li halides are more covalent because 1)high polarisation capabilities of Li ion. 2)small size 3) high tendency to distort electron cloud around negative halide ion.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115112/why-do-we-use-licl-as-a-source-of-chloride-ions-as-nucleophile-but-not-other-alk/115149?r=SearchResults#115149.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the premise of question is false - probably LiI is best soluble in org. solvents, Wikipedia mentions 3430 g/L in methanol! (Only about 40 for LiCl)