# How solubility in alcohol imply covalent nature

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

> lithium chloride is considered to be an ionic compound,but it is soluble in alcohol,which suggests that it also posses a small amount of covalent character.

This is an extract from my book ,when I looked it up it said ionic bonds are polar so they are soluble in alcohol.

So how does lithium chloride's solubility in alcohol prove it has small ammount of covalent character?Is my book wrong ?

Comment: Ever saw chalk? It is ionic. Ever saw sugar? It is covalent. Ever saw a book full of unjustified generalizations?

Comment: A hint can be given, that CaCl2 crystalizes with 6 H2O, or 4 CH3OH, or 3 CH3CH2OH, therefore anhydrous CaCl2 cannot be used for alkohol drying.

Comment: See answers here:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115112/why-do-we-use-licl-as-a-source-of-chloride-ions-as-nucleophile-but-not-other-alk/115149?r=SearchResults#115149

Comment: Also consider that ionic bonds break apart leading to solutions of ions. In a way there is a difference while dissolving, say, NaCl or sugar. The former is an ionic solid and goes into ions, while the second one retains its molecular structure.

Comment: Your title doesn't really match the actual question. This will score badly here so you should fix it.